# $wp_query meta_key naming issue

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

What I am attempting to do is sort posts by custom fields.

I have a few custom fields that don't query properly and I get the 404 page.  The fields that don't work I used hyphens in the naming convention, i.e. `var-name`.  When I switch the hyphens to underscores it works, i.e. `var_name`.

Am I overlooking something simple in PHP or Wordpress that causes conflicts when I do this?

- I know I could simply just switch everything to underscores but I like to know the root of issues so I can avoid them in the future.

I am using `pre_get_posts` to modify the query being executed:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_modify_query' );
function my_modify_query( $wp_query ) {

    if ( is_category() ) {

        // Works - underscore
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['var_name'] ) ) {
            $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'var_name', 'value' => $_REQUEST['var_name'] );
        }

        // Sometimes works - hyphen
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['var-name'] ) ) {
            $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'var-name', 'value' => $_REQUEST['var-name'] );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $meta_query ) ) {
            $wp_query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        }

    }
}
```

Have additional custom fields I check for, the above example is for brevity and clarification and is the same for additional fields.

**EDIT 1**

Here are the queries being run by Wordpress:

The unsuccessful hyphen

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_xxxxx_posts.ID 
FROM wp_xxxxx_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND 0 = 1 
AND wp_xxxxx_posts.post_type IN ('post') 
AND (
    wp_xxxxx_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    OR 
    wp_xxxxx_posts.post_author = 1 
    AND 
    wp_xxxxx_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_xxxxx_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_xxxxx_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The successful underscore

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_xxxxx_posts.ID 
FROM wp_xxxxx_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_j9L3vi_postmeta ON (wp_xxxxx_posts.ID = wp_xxxxx_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_xxxxx_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'custom_post_type' ) 
AND (
    wp_xxxxx_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    OR 
    wp_xxxxx_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_xxxxx_posts.post_status = 'private'
) 
AND ( (
        wp_xxxxx_postmeta.meta_key = 'var_name' 
        AND CAST(wp_xxxxx_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '116'
) ) 
GROUP BY wp_xxxxx_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_xxxxx_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

If I go into phpMyAdmin and simply switch out `var_name` in the above query to `var-name` it works.

**Edit 2**

I am passing the custom fields as so:

```
http://mysite.com/?cat=example&var-name=100
```

Comment: Either your example isn't really your code, or there's something else wrong, because `$meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'var_name', 'value' => $_REQUEST['var_name'];` can't work.

Comment: Sure it does, just not for the hyphenated variable name. `meta_query` for the `WP_Query` object is an array of arrays.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters -> **Multiple Custom Field Handling**.  Then I use the `set` method, `set( $query_var, $value )`, to change the request.

Comment: I think there might be a conflict with a custom taxonomy name and the variable name through the rewrite rules in the database.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You forgot the closing bracket for the array before the semi colon. This **must** break - no alternative to this scenario.

Comment: Okay, not sure how the closing parenthesis got removed above but it is there in my code, I'll update the example above.